# Building SQL query string using table-name as given parameter

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to use string formatting with SQL.
But while passing in variables, these are inserted with quotes and break the syntax.

#### Example

Here I am trying to pass in the table name to the function.

```
def see_results(cur, table):
    print("complete")
    cur.execute(''' SELECT * from %s ''', (table,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)
```

#### Issue

If I pass `"temp_yellow_pages"` as argument the resulting query is: `''' SELECT * from "temp_yellow_pages" '''`.
This breaks.

I can't think of a way to assign anything to the variable `table` without using  `"`'s as `query = temp_yellow_pages` would break as well.

Comment: You cannot pass the name of the table as a query parameter. You would have to insert it into the actual query string.

Comment: Depending on what library you are using, you *might* have something safer than `f"SELECT * from {table}"` available.

Comment: What if I set `table` to be `table = "employee -- drop table employee"` or some other "here be dragons" example of sql based on string concat?

Comment: `psycopg2`, for example, provides `cur.execute(psycopg2.sql.SQL("select * from {}").format(sql.Identifier(table)))`. Note this isn't `str.format`, but a `SQL.format` method that knows about SQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I figured that f-string literal might be the only way but was interested to see if there was some other common solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### String building (prone to SQL injection)

What [khelwood means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658045/removing-quotes-from-variable-before-insertion-into-sql-query-string#comment124908612_70658045):

```py
def selectFrom(table):
    return 'SELECT * FROM ' + table


def see_results(cur, table):
    print("complete")
    cur.execute(selectFrom(table))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)
```

or even using f-strings `cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table}"` directly.

But what if there is malicious input in passed argument `table` like an appended `DROP` or `TRUNCATE` statement (SQL injection)?

#### Query building (safer)

Using SQL capable libraries (*SQL framework* or [database-frontend](https://pypi.org/search/?q=&o=&c=Topic+%3A%3A+Database&c=Topic+%3A%3A+Database+%3A%3A+Front-Ends)) like [*psycopg*](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg/), you can build the SQL using safe methods which apply input-validation.

See the examples in module [`psycopg2.sql`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html?highlight=table#module-psycopg2.sql) to compose an  SQL-statement for a given table parameter.

```py
from psycopg2 import sql

cur.execute(
    sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE values IN (%s, %s)")
        .format(sql.Identifier('my_table')),
    [10, 20])
```